# ng-model vs ngModel - breaks form

Tags: html, css, angularjs, forms, angular-ngmodel

New to angular, new to life:

I have a small email form.

This works:

```
    <form method="post" name="form" role="form" ng-controller="contactForm" ng-submit="form.$valid && sendMessage(input)" novalidate class="form-horizontal">
        <p ng-show="success"><b>We received your message</b></p>
        <p ng-show="error">Something wrong happened!, please try again.</p>

                <label for="name">Name:</label><br>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" ng-model="input.name" required><br>

                <label for="email">Email:</label><br>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" ng-model="input.email" required><br>

                <label for="messsage">Message:</label><br>
                <textarea id="messsage" name="message" ng-model="input.message" ngMaxlength='2000' required></textarea><br>

        <button type="submit" name="submit" ng-disabled="error" value="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

This does not work:

```
    <form method="post" name="form" role="form" ng-controller="contactForm" ng-submit="form.$valid && sendMessage(input)" novalidate class="form-horizontal">
        <p ng-show="success"><b>We received your message</b></p>
        <p ng-show="error">Something wrong happened!, please try again.</p>

                <label for="name">Name:</label><br>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" ngModel="input.name" required><br>

                <label for="email">Email:</label><br>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" ngModel="input.email" required><br>

                <label for="messsage">Message:</label><br>
                <textarea id="messsage" name="message" ngModel="input.message" ngMaxlength='2000' required></textarea><br>

        <button type="submit" name="submit" ng-disabled="error" value="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

for the 2 inputs and the textarea if I use 'ng-model' the email sends, but when the page loads, the form loads invalid.
If i use 'ngModel' the form loads clean, but the email wont submit.

controller here:

```
  app.controller("contactForm", ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.success = false;
    $scope.error = false;

    $scope.sendMessage = function( input ) {
      $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: 'processForm.php',
          data: input,
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
      })
      .success( function(data) {
        if ( data.success ) {
          $scope.success = true;
        $scope.input.name="";
        $scope.input.email="";
        $scope.input.message="";
        } else {
          $scope.error = true;
        }
      } );
    }
```

You can see it live here:
http://smartestdiner.com/Bethel/indexx.html#/contact
Warning:
There is some annoying red background

```
.ng-invalid{
    background-color:red;
}
  }]);
```

That's how we know it is loading invalidly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The annoying red background is the form, since you have a very generic rule set by `.ng-invalid`, the class will be set on the form as well. You would need to make it more specific for the inputs and controls within the form.

Example:

```
input.ng-invalid, 
textarea.ng-invalid {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Or just reset rule for `form.ng-invalid`

---

To add on there is nothing called `ngModel` it is `ng-model`. using the former one doesn't do anything but adds a dummy attribute on the element, it has no effect. It is angular way of directive naming, since html is case insensitive the one way angular can identify the directive from attribute or element name (based on the restriction). It converts it to camelCasing to evaluate and process respective directive (or directives attribute bindings). When you do not have `ng-model` specified and if the form or control does not have `novalidate` attribute, then the browser's HTML5 validation kicks in that is what you see as inconsistency. Using [HTML5 novalidate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) attribute makes sure no native validation happens on the form.

Comment: implemented, thanks
any guess on the ng-modelvs ngModel issues?

Comment: I did not see that part of the question.. :)

Comment: I did not understand what you meant by `for the 2 inputs and the textarea if I use 'ng-model' the email sends, but when the page loads, the form loads invalid. If i use 'ngModel' the form loads clean, but the email wont submit.` ?

Comment: I'm on standby if you want to see anything fiddled with.

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle? I did not understand what your issue is?

Comment: Can you tell me what is your issue?

Comment: check out the new html above, the issue is that if I use 'ng-model' the for loads invalidly, but the email still sends.
If i use 'ngModel' the for will load as valid, but the email will not send.

Comment: DO you want to re-read your comment above? btw i see the form sending email as well in the network console with ng-model.

Comment: oh i got it, there is nothing called `ngModel` it mean there is no `ng-model`

Comment: angular strips the '-' and makes the next letter capital (not sure why, but that is normal functionality)

Comment: @user1815010 That is the way directives are. They are defined camel cased and used in the html with hyphen, because html is case insensitive. Is that your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68249/discussion-between-user1815010-and-psl).

Answer (score 1):

- ng-model is when u write the view (html part).
- ngModel is used when one write a custom directive. It is placed in the "require:" param  so that u can access,
  variables like ngModel.$modelValue

ngModel.$modelValue will have the latest content which has been typed by the user at realtime. So, it can be used for validations, etc.

**View code:-**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plankton">
<head>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/emailing/emailing.directive.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="EmailingCtrl">
   <div> 
       <label>Enter Email: </label>
        <emailing id="person_email" ng-model="email_entered"></emailing>
   </div>      
</body>
</html>
```

**Custom directive**:-

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

angular.module('plankton', [])
       .directive('emailing', function emailing(){
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            replace: 'true',
            template: '<input type="text"></input>',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            scope: {},
            require: "ngModel", 
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel){
              console.log(ngModel); 
                scope.$watch(function(){  return ngModel.$modelValue;
                             }, function(modelValue){
                                 console.log(modelValue);//awesome! gets live data entered into the input text box 
                             });
            }, 
        }; 
       })
       .controller('EmailingCtrl', function($scope){
           var vm = this;

       });
})();
```

This has been plunked here:- [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/cyiegkxu6NrJoOCwOFcI?p=preview)